# How to move first N bytes from text file to another text file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, cut, tail

I've got an extreme problem, and all of the solutions I can imagine are complicated. According to my UNIX/Linux experience there must be an easy way.

I want to delete the first n bytes of file in log.txt.file is long enough. Well, I'm sure somebody will deliver me a suprisingly easy solution I just can't imagine.

Comment: Really bytes?  Or lines?  Look into either `cut -b 123-` or `tail +123`.

Comment: Do you want to move the first N bytes elsewhere, or just remove them entirely?

Answer (score 0):

What about using **tail** with it's **-c** option

from man :

```
 -c, --bytes=K
          output the last K bytes; alternatively, use -c +K to output bytes starting with the Kth of each file
```

so you can do something like 
     tail -c +N log.txt.file

```
 where N is the Number of bytes to delete
```

Example :

```
 [prompt]$ cat file
 ABCDEFGH
 [prompt]$ tail -c +2 file                      //output bytes starting from the second byte
 BCDEFGH
 [prompt]$ tail -c +3 file                     //output bytes starting from the third byte
 CDEFGH
 [prompt]$ tail -c +5 file                     //output bytes starting from the fifth byte
 EFGH

 [prompt]$ ls -l
 -rw-r--r-- 1 user users 9 2014-08-07 10:22 file         // 9 bytes
 [prompt]$ tail -c +S file >> file2                      //this will copy file content to file2 escaping the first 4 bytes
 [prompt]$ ls -l file2                                   
 -rw-r--r-- 1 user users 5 2014-08-07 10:29 file2         // 5 bytes (9 - first 4 bytes)
```

i have to mention that you can use also **--bytes** option to get the last N bytes from a file.

```
  [prompt]$ tail --bytes=5 file              //print the last 5 bytes
  EFGH
```

Comment: no this will not happen because i have to do it simultaneously and in log file some data is also append simultaneously

Comment: @gkp If your question is how to remove first n bytes from a file or how to get the last n bytes from a file, then this completely answer  your question.Apparently i'm not the only one that misunderstood your question, i think your problem is related to "rotating logfile or limiting file size", if it is the case then change your question and please next time be more precise with your questions :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want: Your headline says move first N byte to another file, your text says you want to delete the first N bytes

```
tail -c +N log.txt
```

Will output everything after the first N bytes, so this will answer you text question.
Moving them to another file (as your headline requests) you have to do

```
head -c N log.txt > other.file
```

Comment: i want to delete first n bytes but log file is continuously appended with log every second

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to reinvent a solution to a standard problem that already has a solution.  If this is to avoid logs growing without bounds, you should be looking at `logrotate`.